# memory leak - NSData and NSMutableString

Tags: ios, memory, nsdata, memory-leaks

Parsing a 20MB file that is too large to do in one piece on a 2G iPod touch.  I commented out all code except the NSData/NSMutableString part and stil have the leak.  I don't understand....

support method to read chunk from file:

```
+ (NSData *) dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path atOffset:(off_t)offset withSize:(size_t)bytes  {
    FILE *file = fopen([path UTF8String], "rb");
    if(file == NULL)
        return nil;

    void *data = malloc(bytes);  // check for NULL!
    fseeko(file, offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, 1, bytes, file);  // check return value, in case read was short!
    fclose(file);

    // NSData takes ownership and will call free(data) when it's released
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:bytes];
}
```

and the barebones code that leaks:

```
while( cnt<total) {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSData* data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath atOffset:cnt withSize:MIN(100000,total-cnt)];
    NSString* xmlFragment  = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    cnt+= [xmlFragment length];

    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `alloc-init` every time you are in the loop but there isn't a release so there is a leak in your code.

```
NSString* xmlFragment  = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

There is no balancing `release` for the statement above. If you do,

```
NSString* xmlFragment  = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

It will be deallocated at `[pool drain];`. However the loop seems pointless. You probably meant to do a bit more like add `xmlFragment` to a mutable string perhaps?

Comment: As additional reference, it might be worth reading [how ownership works in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html).

Comment: Thanks! I thought NSAutoreleasePool nuked everything.  And this is a small subset of the method, for clarity. I chased down possible XML parsing bugs for many hours.